# Linker Script: Put a particular file at a later position

Tags: c, linker, embedded, ld, bare-metal

I'd like to write a linker script looking something like this:

```
SECTIONS {
  . = 0x0;
  .startup . : { startup.o(.text) }
  .text : { *(.text) }
  .data : { *(.data) }
  .bss : { *(.bss COMMON) }
  . = 0x4000;
  other.text : { other.o(.text) }
  other.data : { other.o(.data) }
  other.bss : { other.o(.bss) }
}
```

My intention here is to have, in this order:

- a section with the `.text` from `startup.o`
- `.text`, `.data` and `.bss` containing those sections from all other input files *besides `other.o`*
- the `.text`, `.data` and `.bss` sections from `other.o`

Of course there is a problem with the script I've given: `other.o` is included in the `*` wildcards used previously, so it doesn't get put in the output section `other`.

Besides manually listing all the input object files bar `other.o` in place of the `*`s, is there a way I can achieve what I want here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use section attributes to solve this. Suppose you add the following attribute when declaring functions in that file (or any other file):

```
void foo() __attribute__ ((section(".specialmem")));
```

And a similar section definition in your linker script:

```
.specialmem:
{
    *(.specialmem)
}
```

You can do the same thing with data/bss (global variables) as well.
Assuming you want some files/functions to end up in a specific memory location, it is a good practice to define these memory blocks in your linker file as well and then place them there like:

```
.specialmem:
{
    *(.specialmem)
} >specialMemBlock
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try EXCLUDE_FILE

Something like this:
*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*other.o) .text .text.* )

Answer (score 1):

Partial solution: `*` wildcards are fully-fledged file wildcards. If you're lucky enough that `other.o` is in a different directory from the other input files, this will work:

```
SECTIONS {
  . = 0x0;
  .startup . : { foo/startup.o(.text) }
  .text : { foo/*(.text) }
  .data : { foo/*(.data) }
  .bss : { foo/*(.bss COMMON) }
  . = 0x4000;
  other.text : { bar/other.o(.text) }
  other.data : { bar/other.o(.data) }
  other.bss : { bar/other.o(.bss) }
}
```