# Relocate specific object files of a library

Tags: gcc, ld

I have a GCC project for ARM Cortex-M3. The linker script defines where each source section has to be located. So I have sections like this

```
.text : 
{
    *(.text)
} > FLASH
_sidata = .;
.data : AT (_sidata)
{
    _sdata = .;
    *(.data)
    _edata = .;
}
```

The project consumes the library `lib.a` that contains the object file `object.o` and `other.o`. Now I want that the .text section of `object.o` shall be placed between _sdata and _edata. The objectiv is that these section would be copied by the startup code from the FLASH to RAM and it will be executed there. The `other.o` shall not be placed in that section since it's too large.

I tried it like [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21418593/linker-script-put-a-particular-file-at-a-later-position)

```
.data : AT (_sidata)
{
    _sdata = .;
    *(.data)
    object.o(.text)
    _edata = .;
}
```

But this fails since the `object.o` is taken from a library and is not direct available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it by myself. The library must be specififed.

```
.data : AT (_sidata)
{
    _sdata = .;
    *(.data)
    lib.a:object.o(.text)
    _edata = .;
}
```

Comment: or you may use the asterisk (*) symbol acts as a wildcard
    *object.o(.text)